# change game objects color and check if it was clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

the scenario is, i've 15 objects in my scene, each game objects has it own mesh, so i want to change the color of the game object when the player click on it with the mouse, if the player click on the same game objects several times the game objects should change the color randomly, and if the player does not click in the scene within 20 seconds a button should be activated to ask the player to load a new scene, and all my game object should be spawn in the new scene, in the new scene the player has to click on all 15 objects within 15 seconds, if he click on all objects within the 15 seconds the game will over else it the game will reload the first scene,

Comment: This felt a bit muddled. Don’t try and have one routine that determines if any got clicked on but you can have each report “I got clicked” and know of their timer started by making a method on a script that changes colours. Remember the time. And in update checks if time is under your limit fine else note it’s too late and have a mouse down check and if not too late and mouse down then good

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what you are trying to achieve, as I understand you want:

- You have some objects in "sceneA"
- whenever one object is clicked it changes its color randomly (let's say it becomes "activated"
- after ??? seconds an activated objects turns inactivated again going back to the original color
- if the user manages to get them colored (active) all at the same time within 15 seconds a new scene "sceneB" is loaded

So I would rather have a quite simple class on your clickable objects like e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Will hold the references to all currently existing ClickableObject instances
    private static readonly List<ClickableObject> _instances = new List<ClickableObject>();

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;
    
    [Header("debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private bool isActivated;
    [SerializeField] private Color _originalColor;
    
    // public read-only accesses
    public bool IsActivated => isActivated;
    public static IReadOnlyList<ClickableObject> Instances => _instances;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _instances.Add(this);

        if (!_renderer)
        {
            _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        }

        _originalColor = _renderer.material.color;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }

    public void SetActivated(bool activated)
    {
        isActivated = activated;

        _renderer.material.color = activated ? new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f) : _originalColor;
    }
}
```

and then handle the clicks and timeout rather in **one central** controller like e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ClickController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // If possible already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;
    [Header("Settings")]
    // Configure this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private float timeout = 15f;
    // Configure this via the Inspector and select the layer you have assigned to the clickable objects
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask clickableObjectsLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
    // configure this via the Inspector and enter the name or path of your target scene to load
    [SerializeField] private string targetScene = "sceneB";

    // will store a reference to the currently running reset routine
    private Coroutine currenResetRoutine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Initially reset all objects to be not "activated"
        ResetClickableObjects();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // wait for a mouse click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // shoot out a raycast and check if you hit something on the clickableObjectsLayer
            var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, float.PositiveInfinity, clickableObjectsLayer))
            {
                // Just to be sure check if it is really a ClickableObject
                if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent<ClickableObject>(out var clickableObject))
                {
                    // Check if this is not active yet, otherwise ignore the click
                    if (!clickableObject.IsActivated)
                    {
                        // set this object to active -> colored
                        clickableObject.SetActivated(true);

                        // if there is no reset routine running start one with the first clicked object
                        // => from now on have "timout" seconds to click also the rest of the objects
                        if (currenResetRoutine != null)
                        {
                            currenResetRoutine = StartCoroutine(ResetAfterFifteenSecondsRoutine());
                        }

                        // Check if all objects are active at the same time
                        if (ClickableObject.Instances.All(co => co.IsActivated))
                        {
                            // cancel the reset routine
                            StopCoroutine(currenResetRoutine);
                            
                            // load the targetScene after 2 seconds
                            // just to have time for e.g. a "YEAH YOU DID IT YOU AWESOME USER!"
                            // we use "Invoke" since it also works on a disabled component
                            Invoke(nameof(LoadScene), 2f);
                            
                            // disable this component so no clicks are tracked anymore
                            enabled = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadScene()
    {
        // Go to the target scene configured in the Inspector
        SceneManager.LoadScene(targetScene);
    }
    
    private static void ResetClickableObjects()
    {
        // Reset all ClickableObject to be not activated
        foreach (var clickableObject in ClickableObject.Instances)
        {
            clickableObject.SetActivated(false);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ResetAfterFifteenSecondsRoutine()
    {
        // wait for the timeout configured in the Inspector
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeout);
        
        // Then reset all ClickableObject to be not activated
        ResetClickableObjects();

        // reset to allow the next timeout to begin
        currenResetRoutine = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check what i wrote above, i think like that it will be clear and easy to help me, thank you...

Comment: @jonathanpascal I'm not here to implement byoyr game for you to be honest ..  I think I answered your original question and at least gave you an idea how to adopt it now to your new requests ..